# How to implement a "command line" similar to vim in my curses program

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, curses

i am new to python and wanted to make a small to-do list program using curses for fun.

this is the basic code i have right now:

```
import curses

mylist = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

def main(stdscr):
    y = 1
    x = 1

    for item in mylist:
        stdscr.addstr(y, x, item)
        y += 1

    stdscr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

it creates a window and displays each item from "mylist", i wanted to extend this so that a user could enter a command to, say, add a new task to the list and have the screen update to display the new task, how could i go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `curses.echo()` and `stdscr.getstr(x, y)` it then displays whatever you enter.

```
import curses

mylist = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

def main(stdscr):
    curses.echo()
    y = 1
    x = 1

    for item in mylist:
        stdscr.addstr(y, x, item)
        y += 1
    new_item = stdscr.getstr(y, x)

curses.wrapper(main)
```